# Froward authenticated users from PHP app to Django

Tags: php, django, authentication

I'm building a web app on Django. My company has a PHP web app that employees are currently using. There already exists an user authentication system on the PHP web app. Is it possible to authenticate users on the web app then forward them to my app as authenticated users?

We already have a rest API installed for forward some data from the PHP app to Django. Would this simplify the process?

Comment: The answers to your questions are yes and yes. What code have you written so far?

Comment: Oof...a lot lol. At the moment, I am using Azure Active Directory for user authentication (i.e. have them log in with their work emails). I am not particularly attached to this however. Because I am using Azure AD, my Users app is pretty slim.

Comment: If your auth system issues or could be modified to issue [JWTs](https://jwt.io/introduction/), that might be a good approach. I've used them for auth across microservices, and while I did not enjoy working with the microservices, the JWTs worked extremely well.

Comment: One way would be to just keep the session based auth and use the PHP app as an "Auth Service" of sorts. You could just expose an endpoint in the PHP app that validates the session. Your Python app can have middlware that sends the session from a cookie over to the PHP app to authenticate the user.

Comment: I say that because without CSRF tokens JWT can be a security vulnerability. So you end up needing a centralised store anyway (which is what most people think they're getting away from by using JWT) for the CSRF tokens. Unless you're leveraging the other attributes of JWT I don't think there's any benefit to switching.